# fail to run maven on jenkins on a closed environment

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to run a simple build using maven on jenkins (1.651.2) for windows. I am working on a closed environment which has no internet connection. Trying the same on my internet PC works fine. Also from command line everything works fine on jenkins I get this error:

```
Building on master in workspace C:\source\maven
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.tools.ZipExtractionInstaller.performInstallation(ZipExtractionInstaller.java:79)
        at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
        at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:108)
        at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
        at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:143)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:357)
        at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2229)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:938)
        at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractMavenBuild.java:56)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.getEnvironment(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:166)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:622)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

adding my simple program pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">    
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>    
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>    
  <packaging>jar</packaging>    
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>    
  <name>my-app</name>    
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>    
  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>    
      <groupId>junit</groupId>    
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>    
      <version>3.8.1</version>    
      <scope>test</scope>    
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>    
</project>
```

Comment: Show your main pom.xml

Comment: added pom.xml as requested. I will emphasize that this works on my internet machine and not on the closed environment (meanning no internet connection),

Comment: If you don't have internet connection how can maven download dependencies?

Comment: i downloaded all dependencies to a repo and set maven to work offline.and as I said running mvn from command line on the closed system works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Jenkins is trying to automatically install maven, please check your configuration page if you have something similar to this (*Install automatically* checked):

[image]

If so, please uncheck that box and provide the path to the maven installation, or leave it blank if you have maven in PATH of jenkins user.

Answer (score 0):

thank for krzyk
The problem was not the maven section which was set as krzyk suggested the problem was in the jdk section which had "Install automatically" checked. The Error message was unclear